# Changing image src via MVC 3 Action

Tags: jquery, image, asp.net-mvc-3, src

I have a page with an image tag.  The image displayed by the image tag changes depending on an image selection made on a popup window.  The following are the steps to reproduce my issues:

```
 1. Click button on Main Page and display popup with selectable images
 2. Click any one image in popup to create selection
 3. Click "Associate" button in popup to begin association process
     a. JQuery.post is called to "Associate" selected image to image in Main page
        i. Code in the Controller is run and save the association in the database.
     b. Upon success, the "success" function of the JQuery.post makes a call to an existing javascript function.
        i. This function creates a string in the following format: "{Controller}/{Action}/{PrimaryId}/{SecondaryId}"
        ii. In the function, the "src" of the image in the main page is set to the string created above.
        iii. The change in "src" makes the code in the controller run which in turn returns the specified image.
        iv. The popup is closed
```

For all practical purposes, the code is working except for the annoying issue that regardless of browser, the image does not refresh upon returning from the Controller via the process described above(during the JQuery.post "Success" function).

One thing to note, is that if steps "b.i" - "b.iv" are run without "JQuery.post" (ie. just retrieving image data without doing an association first) the image gets refreshed every time.  The code used is below (redacted - items in curly bracket are place holders)

IMAGE MODIFIED

```
<div id="divMenuItemMedia">
   <img id="imgMenuItemMedia" alt='someAlt' src='/{Controller}/{Action}/{InitialImageId}' />
</div>
```

BUTTON TO BRING UP POPUP

```
<input type="button" id="btnModifyImage" name="btnModifyImage" class="t-button" value="Change Image" onclick="showImageChooser();" />
```

JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS

MAIN PAGE

```
function GetCurrentMediaItemsByIds(pId, iId) {
        //$('#imgMenuItemMedia').load(function () {
            //alert("Image updated");
       // });
        var imgMedia = document.getElementById("imgMenuItemMedia");
        var sourceUrl = '/{Controller}/{Action}/{pId}/{iId}';
        //$('#imgMenuItemMedia').attr("src", sourceUrl);
        imgMedia.src = sourceUrl;
        InImageSelectionMode = false;
    }

function showImageChooser() {
        var url = '{Controller}/{DataGetterActionForPopup}';
        ShowPopup(url, "#MediaChooserDialog", null);
    }
```

POPUP

```
function associateMediaSelection(e) {
   // The entity name is saved in hidden field in the "Edit" page
   var entityName = document.getElementById("hidEntityName").value;
   var contentPath = entityName + "/Associate" + entityName + "ToMediaItem";
   var url = '{Controller}/{Action}';
   var primaryId = {pId};
   var secondaryId = {sId};
   var entityId = {eId};
   var data = { "entityId" : eId, "primaryId": pId, "secondaryId": sId };

   var jqxhr = $.post(url, data, function (e) {
                GetCurrentMediaItemsByIds(presentationId, document.getElementById("hid" + entityName + "Id").value);

                closeMediaSelection();
            });
        }
function closeMediaSelection()
        {
            var windowPopup = $("#MediaChooserDialog").data('tWindow');
            windowPopup.close();
        }
```

Anyone have an idea as to what may be preventing the image refresh?

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming here this is the full, real code. In that case:

```
var sourceUrl = '/{Controller}/{Action}/{pId}/{iId}';
```

will be an issue, as this means nothing in javaascript. Yon can insert:

```
var sourceUrl = '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")'
```

where Action and Controller are filled in with the names of your controller/action method.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, "var sourceUrl = '/{Controller}/{Action}/{pId}/{iId}';" is fake and text inside {} are just placeholders for the real text in my code (needed to obfuscate somthings as to not disclose what my code is about)

Comment: Also, "var sourceUrl = '/{Controller}/{Action}/{pId}/{iId}';" is just the output as seen by the client, the actual code does make use of '@Url.Action..' and '@Url.Content....' as needed.

Comment: sorry, there was quite a bit of detail to try to keep track of there above

Comment: so "imgMedia.src = sourceUrl;" is where the image seemingly does not get refreshed then, right? If you load up fiddler, do you see this getting called or if you set breakpoints, is this code actually hit? Does fiddler show a valid image being returned? If I understand correctly, if you set this via a simply javascript function it works, but when going back through jquery it doesnt?

Comment: Yes, "imgMeda.src = sourceUrl;" is where the change occurs.  I'm not familiar with using fiddler, but by looking via FireFox's Developer tools, I can see the "src" attribute has changed correctly.  Also, the correct "Action" in the controller is fired correctly after the "src" change,  but the image just does not update.  I'm now guessing that it may be because "JQuery.post" runs in its own thread while "imgMedia" runs on the UI thread.... just a guess.

Comment: for giggles, try purely through jquery to set to a DIFFERENT image url: $("#imgMenuItemMedia").attr("src", "images/testimage.jpg");   of course filling in with a known image to ensure this is firing off ok. I've never ran into winforms type thread updating issues in jquery, so I first have to imagine something else is going on. If your image src is the same it could be a caching type issue. Try adding random data to the url as shown here: http://www.devcha.com/2009/11/how-to-dynamically-changerefresh-image.html

Comment: No giggles needed.  I've done that already (also stated in the original question) and it works every time (whether the image is explicit, ie. "imageName.jpg", or Action Method-retrieved).  That's why I think is a JQuery.post vs. UI thread.  But if that is the case, I've no idea how to overcome it.

Comment: I see nowhere you used jquery to set the src attribute and I see nowhere this is randomized. In addition use fiddler to ensure a valid image is coming back. Its easy. Install it, load it, do the request, go into fiddler and click on the request and there should be an image tab(along those lines) on the bottom right to see the resulting image.  I have no idea from the large paragraph above and no actual test project whats getting called when and can best guess at it.

Comment: Tried fiddler.  It only registers the JQurey.post request, but it does not register the "GET" request that ocurrs when "imgMedia.src" is changed (this via the "success" function of the JQuery.post).  However, it does register the "GET" request and displays the returned image in the "ImageView" tab when "imgMedia.src" is changed directly (without doing the JQuery.post).

Comment: then it would mean to me the request isn't even going out - I thought you said though the code runs when you set the source? So to clarify, when you set imgMedia.src - the controller code definitely gets hit but fiddler shows nothing?

Comment: The request does go out.  I can step through it in the Controller every time and can confirm that the Action Method is returning a byte array containing the data for the image just like it does when JQuery.post is not involved.  So, I can confirm that fiddler shows nothing when the imgMedia.src change occurs from within the "success" function of JQuery.post.

Comment: and this is for a randomized new url? if you have a sample repro project, I can fix it, guaranteed : )   its weird its not showing up in fiddler, although sometimes if its localhost you need ipv4.fiddler as your local address depending on which browser.

Comment: Not a complete answer to my own question, but by doing the following, I was able solve the issue in about 90% of the attempts:`var jqxhr = $.post(url, data, function (e) {
                GetCurrentMediaItemsByIds(presentationId, document.getElementById("hid" + entityName + "Id").value);
               setTimeout("closeMediaSelection()", 1000);
            });
        }`.  Apparently, the issue seems to be not enough time between the function that sets "src" and the function that closes the window where this javascript call resides.

Comment: After I made the change above, I was able to see the correct image being returned in "ImageView" tab in fiddler.  I failed a few times, but I'm guessing it was due to the size of the images and they not being fully downloaded before the 1000 milliseconds were up.